# How do I pop_back an entire row in Mutlidimensional Vector in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I am having trouble erasing an entire row from my multidimensional vector in c++. I want to store N L-dimensional unique vectors. I tried doing something like this:

```
 vector< vector<int > > my_vec;
 for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    my_vec.push_back(vector<int>());

    for(j=0;j<L;j++){
        t =(int)(distribution(engine)*Tr); //JUST A RANDOM NUMBER GENERATOR
        traits[i].push_back(t);
        }

    if ( array unique ){
        ALL GOOD !
        }
    else{ my_vec[i].pop_back();i--;} // THIS IS GIVING ME PROBLEMS.
    }
```

The reason I need a vector is that in the code that follows the dimensions will change.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you mean `my_vec.pop_back()` ? But then your next iteration will try to access an item beyond the bounds of the vector, since it still uses `i` as an index.

Comment: You are not erasing the i^th row, but the last element of the i^th row which is a different thing. To erase an element of any vector, call `vec.erase(vec.begin() + i)`. Note that this is generally not a fast operation if you don't delete at the end.

Comment: Yes I mean my_vec.pop_back()

Comment: You are right sorry for the sloppiness, that i acutally a pseudo-code, I am just looking for a way to erase the whole row.

Comment: Another comment: For performance you should reserve space: `my_vec.reserve(N)`. This is a good idea if you know the size in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to erase an item from a vector, call the `vector::erase` method, and give it an iterator to the item to erase.  It doesn't matter if the item to erase is another vector.

Here is a small sample.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<vector<int>> VecInt2D;

void erase_a_row(VecInt2D& v, size_t where)
{
    if ( !(where >= 0 && where < v.size()))
       return;
    v.erase(v.begin() + where);
}

int main() {
    VecInt2D myVect(10);
    cout << myVect.size() << "\n";
    // erase the last item
    erase_a_row(myVect, myVect.size() - 1);
    cout << myVect.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Live sample: http://ideone.com/xvDpjT